# Parse.com library doesn't work in my android app

Tags: android, parse-platform

When i run my app without parse library it works just fine, but once i add these two lines:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
```

the app doesn't work and this is what it shows me
[image]

Comment: run gradle from command line and post the complete error log

Comment: how can i do that? am not used to command line

Answer (score 0):

Download parse sdk and add it into libs folder.
"**compile fileTree('libs')**" copy and paste this line in your gradle.

If this answer work for you please mark it.